# Align letter body in scrlttr2 with adressfield

Tags: horizontal-alignment, koma-script, scrlttr2

How can I align the body of the following letter with the adressfield. More precisely the text generated by

```
\setkomavar{subject}{\bfseries Subject}

\opening{Dear Mr. XY,}
\lipsum[6]       
\closing{Best regards}
```

should be alignet with the text generated by `\begin{letter}{Mr. XY\\\TeX-Street \\ \LaTeX-City}`

```
\documentclass[papaer=a4,refline=wide,enlargefirstpage=on]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{letter}{Mr. XY\\\TeX-Street \\ \LaTeX-City}

\setkomavar{subject}{\bfseries Subject}

\opening{Dear Mr. XY,}
\lipsum[6]   
\closing{Best regards}

\end{letter}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: Since there are no answers up to now I add this to the question and don't post a new one:

Is is also possible to align the right side of the body text with the right side of the date?

**Edit2**: From the answers up to now I see that I should clarify a point: I don't want to move the adressfield. Instead I want to enlarge the width of the body, such that it is alignet with the addressfield and with the date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `refline=wide` to align the date, and change `toaddrhpos` to align the address (it will no longer be at the correct place for a DIN-window) or as alternative change `\oddsidemargin`.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,enlargefirstpage=on]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\makeatletter
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{%
  \dimexpr 1in +\oddsidemargin\relax}
%\oddsidemargin=\dimexpr\useplength{toaddrhpos}-1in\relax  
\makeatother  
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{letter}{Mr. XY\\\TeX-Street \\ \LaTeX-City}

\setkomavar{subject}{\bfseries Subject}

\opening{Dear Mr. XY,}
\lipsum[6]
\closing{Best regards}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Why does one need the `1in`, seems to be adjusted manually...