# How to put sender address to the right on top of date in scrlttr2

Tags: scrlttr2

I am using `scrlttr2` instead of the default `letter` for the various extra features it offers, but I want the `fromaddress` to be on top of the date and not in the page header. So I want it to look just like the default `letter` puts it.

Is there any way I could remove the sender address from the header and put it on the date (with just one line of space)?

I have this preamble so far:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,parskip=full]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\KOMAoptions{foldmarks=off,backaddress=false,fromalign=right}

\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
```

This puts the from address in the header on the right and not aligned with the date. I want it to be lower (just over the date) and aligned with the date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have made a reasonable start.  `scrlettr2` divides the page up in to various regions.  At the top is a header region.  Below that on the left is a region for the address the letter is to be sent to.  At about the same level on the right-hand side is a region called `location`.

The option you choose `fromalign=right` moves the from address to the right, but keeps it in the header area.  Instead the option `fromalign=locationright`, wiil move it down in to the location region.

Now by default the date appears in the reference line, a box placed below all these addresses.  The date can be removed from that position, via the option `refline=nodate`.  It can then be placed in the location region, by setting the koma variable `location` to the value of the koma variable `date`:

```
\setkomavar{location}{\usekomavar{date}}
```

Putting this together we get:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,parskip=full]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\KOMAoptions{foldmarks=off,backaddress=false,fromalign=locationright,refline=nodate}

\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}

\setkomavar{fromname}{John Public} 
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Valley 2\\
  54321 Public-Village}
\setkomavar{location}{\usekomavar{date}}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Addressee\\Road\\Town\\County}
\opening{Dear Sir,} 
A short text that constitutes the body of the letter.
\closing{Yours sincerely}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Should you wish to have more space before the date you can change the definition you give to `location`.  For example,

```
\setkomavar{location}{\vspace{\baselineskip}\usekomavar{date}}
```

produces a blank line before the date:

[image: Blank line before date]

Comment: Thanks that makes it look much better. The only remaining issue however is that the `location` with the fromaddress and the date is not aligned properly with the body text of the letter. It goes out like 1cm more or something to the right further than the letter's body which looks really awkward. Any idea how to make them aligned?

Comment: The questions of aligning the margins is addressed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50594/15925 .  Note however, by default the recepient address is meant to be positioned within the window of an envolope.

Comment: I already did see that, but I have no `refline=wide` in my case, but it is still making things wide. I don't want it to be positioned within the window of an envelope, its not going to be posted, its just a formal document in the form of a letter (like a reference letter).

Comment: You need the code in that answer adjusting `toaddrhpos`, i.e. `\makeatletter \@setplength{toaddrhpos}{\dimexpr 1in +\oddsidemargin\relax} \makeatother` in your preamble.

Comment: Erm, I have no toaddress in my letter. Its the from address I have to move (on the right). I tried using the same code but with `fromaddrhpos`, nothing happened. :(

Comment: The code I gave you above in the comment pulled in both addresses for me.  However, for just adjusting the location it is the variable `lochpos` you need, see `scrguien` (at [ctan](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/) ) page 296.  So `\makeatletter \@setplength{lochpos}{1in} \makeatother` will work.

Comment: Sorry got confused now. What do I need to do with `scrguien`? Import it as a package or change the document class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8099/discussion-between-andrew-swann-and-jbx)

Comment: A visualization of the different areas in the scrlttr2 class can be seen in the manual: https://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#page=165

Comment: Ah wrong page - The correct page is 166, not 165. Unfortunately, I am no longer allowed to edit my comment -.-